# Change Bootstrap tooltip text from Angular 2 input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am using Angular 2 and Bootstrap 3 [tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips). I have a side bar in layout and a main content screen. In the side bar the user can change the tooltip text of an item in the content.

Jokes on me though because the tooltip text isn't updating. So an object is passed into my content panel with the tooltip text via `@Input()`. Then is data bound via `[attr.title]=panel.tooltiptext`.

Now if you update the tooltip text then hover over the text you see that the tooltip text **wasn't** updated but keep hovering and you will see vanilla html title pop up with the correct text.

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uZvQ3BjbwPfEpL4b3ara?p=preview)** example

**main.component.ts** - This is like my side bar, it is at a higher level than the content panel.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{desc}}</h2>

      <tooltip-comp [panel]="panelObj"></tooltip-comp> <br>

      <input [(ngModel)]="panelObj.tooltipText" style="width: 250px;" />
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  desc:string = 'Change tooltip text';
  panelObj = {
    tooltipText: "The Power of the "
  };

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

**tooltip.component.ts** - This is the content panel that gets the object with the updated tooltip text in it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tooltip-comp',
  template: `
    <div>
      <a id="blah" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" [attr.title]="panel.tooltipText">You Don't Know</a> <br><br>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class TooltipComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() panel: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({container: 'body', html: true});
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `data-original-title` attribute to dynamically update your tooltip.

```
[attr.data-original-title]="panel.tooltipText"
```

**[Modified Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/xcjbcVnS5PfuZJiJ3yki?p=preview)**

Comment: I am using this in React, and it does not behave as expected. I am conditioning the title `data-original-title={isTrue ? "this text" : "that text"}` which works, but you have to mouse out and mouse back in to see the change..How do you make the text change while the tooltip is already visible?